# Expo React Sticky Notification for Player

Tags: android, audio-player, expo-av, expo-notifications

I want to add sticky notification for my android audio player and handle the player via app notification but I don't know how I can do this I tried expo official notification documents but failed please help me in this case.

```html
useEffect(() => {
    async function body() {
      Notifications.dismissAllNotificationsAsync();

      const localNotification = {
        title: 'this.state.notifTitle',
        body: 'this.state.notifMessage',
        android: {
          sticky: true,
          priority: 'max',
        },
      };
      Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification);
    }

    body();

   //  Notifications.addListener((n) => {
   //    console.log('notificationss', n);
   //  });
  }, []);
```